# Tree-like Graph drawing with probabilities

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-trees, graphs

As the title says, I'm having trouble drawing tree-like graph in LaTeX.
Using TexSE I found the library “Tikz” and I tried to cook up something without success.

A little part of the gigantic (sigh!) graph that I need to put on my thesis is here:
[image]

Any help is appreciated.

edit: I forgot to put the code for the best attempt I managed to do. Please be kind.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance={15mm}, thick, main/.style = {draw, circle}]
\node[main] (1) {$C$}; 
\node[main] (2) [below left of=1] {$C_{00}$};
\node[main] (3) [right  of=2] {$C_{01}$}; 
\node[main] (4) [below right of=1] {${C_10}$};
\node[main] (5) [right  of=4] {$C_{11}$}; 
\draw[->] (1) -- (2);
\draw[->]  (1) -- (3);
\draw[->]  (1) -- (4);
\draw[->]  (1) -- (5);

\end{tikzpicture}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your complete ' gigantic' tree is something like your example, which is very repetitive, it's easy to draw with a `\foreach` sentence (or serveral, nested or otherwise).

Something like this:

```
\documentclass[border=2mm,tikz]{standalone}

\tikzset
{%
  empty/.style={minimum size=0,inner sep=0,outer sep=0},
  circled/.style={circle,draw}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[circled] (O2) at (11,8) {$\mathcal{C}$};
\node[empty]   (O1) at (11,6) {};
\draw[-latex]  (O2) -- (O1) node[pos=0.8,right] {$\tau$};;
\foreach[count=\j]\i in {00,01,10,11} 
{%
  \node[circled] (A\j) at (4*\j,0)   {$\mathcal{C}_{\i0}$};
  \node[circled] (B\j) at (4*\j+2,0) {$\mathcal{C}_{\i1}$};
  \node[circled] (D\j) at (4*\j+1,4) {$\mathcal{C}_{\i}$};
  \draw (A\j) --++ (1,2) node[midway, left] {$\frac{1}{2}$} 
                         node[empty] (C\j)  {} -- (B\j)
                         node[midway,right] {$\frac{1}{2}$};
  \draw[-latex] (D\j) -- (C\j) node [pos=0.8,right] {$\tau^3$};
  \draw (O1) -- (D\j) node[pos=0.7,above] {$\frac{1}{4}$};
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: So helpful, thank you!